10D quotes for FX volatility smile calibration
When calibrating fx smile using SABR and Vanna Volga,
Are 10D-RR and 10D-BF used?
Or 25D and ATM quotes are used only?
If 10D is used, which currency pairs use 10D quotes?
If I use 10D quote for calibration,
Should I add terms with respect to 10D Market strangle and 10D RR to the objective function?
When I try to use VV approximation for 10D,
Parameter and variable for calibration would be
sigma_s= 10d smile strangle vol and
sigma1=10d put,
sigma2=atm,
sigma3=10d call,
Right?
